# c# WASM Uikit notification with parameters

Tags: c#, uikit, blazor-webassembly

i have a problem to call a uikit notification and set the position and timeout

uikit original:

```
#1 UIkit.notification('My message');
#2 UIkit.notification('My message', status);
#3 UIkit.notification('My message', { /* options */ });
#4 UIkit.notification({ /* options */ });
```

this works but there is no position or timeout

```
_IJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("UIkit.notification", new[] { label, color});
```

code:

```
private IJSRuntime _IJSRuntime { get; set; }
public UIKit(IJSRuntime iJSRuntime)
{
  _IJSRuntime = iJSRuntime;
}


public void Notification(string label, string color, string position = "bottom-right")
{
    _IJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("UIkit.notification", "{" + $"message:'{label}', status:'{color}', timeout:5000, pos:'{position}'" + "}" );
}
```

can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not my favorite but my solution is:

Create a new js file "UiKitCustom.js"

```
function Notification(label, color, timeout, position) {
UIkit.notification({
    message: label,
    status: color,
    timeout: timeout,
    pos: position
});
}
```

and call this function

```
await _IJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Notification", new[] { $"{label}", $"{color}", $"{timeoute}", $"{position}" });
```

But i hope someone give me a better way :)